Build Error: OBJECT is a namespace but is used as a type
I am trying to implement an ASP.NET Core MVC app, and the following code throws an error:

'AdverseEventReport' is a namespace but is used like a type

From what I have been able to gather this has to do with an instantiation issue. Any help that can be offered will be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your help.
Here is the model class:
namespace AdverseEventReportAPP.Models
{
    public class AdverseEventReport
    {
        public required string Date { get; set; }
        public required string PatientID { get; set; }
        public required string PreExistingConditions { get; set; }
        public required string AdverseSymptoms { get; set; }
        public required string Severity { get; set; }
        public bool ReportableToFDA { get; set; }
        public required string Reasoning { get; set; }
        public required string DrugName { get; set; }
        public required string DrugType { get; set; }
        public required string ReasonForTaking { get; set; }
    }
}

Here is the code for the controller:
using AdverseEventReportAPP.Models; // Ensure the correct model namespace is used

namespace AdverseEventReportApp.Controllers
{
    public class AdverseEventController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            // Correct instantiation of the AdverseEventReport model
            var model = new AdverseEventReportAPP
            {
                Date = "2024-10-21",
                PatientID = "12345",
                PreExistingConditions = "None",
                AdverseSymptoms = "Headache, Dizziness",
                Severity = "Moderate",
                ReportableToFDA = true,
                Reasoning = "Critical side effect",
                DrugName = "Aspirin",
                DrugType = "Analgesic",
                ReasonForTaking = "Pain Relief"
            };

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Submit(AdverseEventReport model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Save logic here
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View("Index", model);
        }
    }
}

Here is the code for the form:
@model AdverseEventReportAPP.Models.AdverseEventReport

<form asp-action="Submit" method="post">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://localhost/AdverseEvent/images/AdverseBanner.jpg" alt="" width="508" height="67" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr><td><hr /></td></tr>
    </table>

    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;"><strong>Date:</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 65%;"><input type="text" name="Date" value="@Model.Date" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;"><strong>Patient ID:</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 65%;"><input type="text" name="PatientID" value="@Model.PatientID" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;"><strong>Pre-existing Conditions:</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 65%;"><input type="text" name="PreExistingConditions" value="@Model.PreExistingConditions" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;"><strong>Adverse Symptoms:</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 65%;"><input type="text" name="AdverseSymptoms" value="@Model.AdverseSymptoms" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;"><strong>Severity:</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 65%;"><input type="text" name="Severity" value="@Model.Severity" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;"><strong>Reportable to FDA:</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 65%;"><input type="checkbox" name="ReportableToFDA" @(Model.ReportableToFDA ? "checked" : "") /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;"><strong>Reasoning:</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 65%;"><input type="text" name="Reasoning" value="@Model.Reasoning" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr><td><hr /></td></tr>
    </table>

    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;"><strong>Drug Name:</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 65%;"><input type="text" name="DrugName" value="@Model.DrugName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;"><strong>Drug Type:</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 65%;"><input type="text" name="DrugType" value="@Model.DrugType" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 20%;"><strong>Reason for taking Medication:</strong></td>
            <td style="width: 65%;"><input type="text" name="ReasonForTaking" value="@Model.ReasonForTaking" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr><td><hr /></td></tr>
    </table>

    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://localhost/AdverseEvent/images/Blue_Prism_AWS_Partnership.jpg" alt="" width="320" height="104" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


Here:  var model = new AdverseEventReportAPP  -- APP is your name space, without APP is the class you defined.  You can instantiate a class object, not a namespace.

You have something strange that you might added after you modified the code:
public IActionResult Index()
{
    // Correct instantiation of the AdverseEventReport model
    var model = new AdverseEventReportAPP
    {
        Date = "2024-10-21",
        PatientID = "12345",
        PreExistingConditions = "None",
        AdverseSymptoms = "Headache, Dizziness",
        Severity = "Moderate",
        ReportableToFDA = true,
        Reasoning = "Critical side effect",
        DrugName = "Aspirin",
        DrugType = "Analgesic",
        ReasonForTaking = "Pain Relief"
    };

    return View(model);
}

Where you have new AdverseEventReportAPP. Where did you make the class with identical name of your root namespace? This part should be corrected. I believe it should be var model = new AdverseEventReport.
If you have a namespace collision, then you could add alias to the namespace. Example:
using MyAlias = AdverseEventReportAPP.Models;

namespace AdverseEventReportApp.Controllers
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Submit(MyAlias.AdverseEventReport model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Save logic here
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View("Index", model);
    }
}

For the view:
@using MyAdverseEventReport = AdverseEventReportAPP.Models.AdverseEventReport
...

But I would recommend to review your namespacing convention across the project...
